# BigQuery Arrays - Relative Position Navigation

Tags: google-bigquery

**UPDATE**:  While navigation works, issue is now using it - accessing the fields in the anonymous struct generated (cant access fields by name)- so the navigation worked, but Im missing something so that the result is actually accessible?

I answered my own question as I was filling this in,  but felt to share this anyway (WITH OFFSET was the key thing I wasnt aware of). I was looking how to achieve 'navigational' capabilities when processing arrays (look forward / back 'n' - similar to Lag/Lead).  In this example, I create a struct with the next and previous values:

```
WITH items AS
  (SELECT ["apples", "bananas", "pears", "grapes"] as list)

SELECT
  list AS original_list, 
  ARRAY(SELECT (item, list[SAFE_OFFSET(pos+1)], list[SAFE_OFFSET(pos-1)]) FROM UNNEST(list) item WITH OFFSET pos) new_list
FROM
  items
```

produces...

```
[("apples","bananas",NULL), ("bananas","pears","apples"), ("pears", "grapes", "bananas"), ("grapes", NULL, "pears")]
```

Works great - so my last question is how I can alias the names of the structs fields, BQ validation gives a parsing error, is it possible?  or can it only be '_field_1' anonymous ones?

i.e AS X, AS Next, AS Previous

```
ARRAY(SELECT (item AS X, list[SAFE_OFFSET(pos+1)] AS Next, list[SAFE_OFFSET(pos-1)] AS Previous) FROM UNNEST(list)
```

'Expected ")" or "," but got keyword AS' - is this possible?

One interesting twist on this could be some calculations over previous, what if I wanted to know not just the previous, but the previous 'MIN' value relative to this row for all previous?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, thanks - I will for sure when complete, issue I have is I cant assess the fields because they are now anonymous in the struct, and thus you cant access them by name as a result?  So not its not currently usable without some help

Comment: It's still an array. To access the items of the array, you should unnest it. After nesting, the item will be a struct (named part). Let's say you used UNNEST(new_list) as new_list_item. Then you should use new_list_item.next, new_list_item.prev to access them. Another example is coming in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so my last question is how I can alias the names of the structs fields, BQ validation gives a parsing error, is it possible? or can it only be '_field_1' anonymous ones?

Your original query was very close - you just missed using keyword `STRUCT`

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  list AS original_list, 
  ARRAY(
    SELECT STRUCT(item AS X, list[SAFE_OFFSET(pos+1)] AS Next, list[SAFE_OFFSET(pos-1)] AS Previous) 
    FROM UNNEST(list) item WITH OFFSET pos) new_list
FROM
  items
```

Or, you could use `AS STRUCT` as in example below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  list AS original_list, 
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT item AS X, list[SAFE_OFFSET(pos+1)] AS Next, list[SAFE_OFFSET(pos-1)] AS Previous
    FROM UNNEST(list) item WITH OFFSET pos
  ) new_list
FROM
  items
```

Comment: Thanks Mikhail! 1 word, I did think it should have worked - cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You should use struct to give them names.

```
WITH items AS
  (SELECT ["apples", "bananas", "pears", "grapes"] as list)

SELECT
  list AS original_list, 
  (
    SELECT ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(item, next, prev))
    FROM (
      SELECT l AS item, LAG(l) OVER (order by o) as prev, LEAD(l) OVER (order by o) as next
      FROM UNNEST(list) l WITH OFFSET o
      ORDER BY o
    )
  ) as new_list
FROM
  items
```

To access them, you need to unnest them. An example is:

```
WITH 
items AS
(
    SELECT 1 as id, ["apples", "bananas", "pears", "grapes"] as list union all
    SELECT 2 as id, ["strawberries", "oranges", "kiwis", "figs"] as list
),
grouped AS
(
  SELECT
    id,
    list AS original_list, 
    (
      SELECT ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(item, next, prev))
      FROM (
        SELECT l AS item, LAG(l) OVER (order by o) as prev, LEAD(l) OVER (order by o) as next
        FROM UNNEST(list) l WITH OFFSET o
        ORDER BY o
      )
    ) as new_list
  FROM
    items
)
SELECT id, list_item.item, list_item.next, list_item.prev
FROM grouped
JOIN UNNEST(new_list) as list_item
```

Comment: Thanks makes sense appreciated.